# Нужно составить регулярное выражение (RegEx) для исключения чисел, делящихся на 5 нацело

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pcre

Нужно составить регулярное выражение (RegEx) для исключения чисел, делящихся на 5 нацело. 5, 10, 15, ... 12945 и так далее. Если число делиться на пять, то нам оно не нужно.

Сейчас я использую следующую регулярку: `^(?!(([1-9]{1,999}[05]{1,999})|5)).*?$`

Логика следующая: Числа, заканчивающиеся на 0 или 5 кроме ноля, или 5.
Но для числел **с двумя или более нолями** или **с двумя или более пятёрками** эта регулярка не срабатывает.

Как быть?

Comment: `^((\d*[1-46-9])|5)$` https://regex101.com/r/K6DTQG/3

Answer (score 1):

[Ваше регулярное выражение](https://regex101.com/r/9lqFIK/3) (упрощу его до `^(?!([1-9]{1,999}[05]{1,999}|5)).*$`, так как нежадный квантификатор приведёт к идентичному результату, а одна из подмасок лишняя) находит любую строку, которая не начинается с (все регулярные выражения типа `^(?!<только-не-этот-шаблон>).*$` означают именно это) `([1-9]{1,999}[05]{1,999}|5)`, то есть с `5` или 1-999 отличных от нуля цифр, за которыми следует 1-999 цифр `0` или `5`.

Вы можете использовать

```
^(?!(?:5|[1-9]\d*[05])$)
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/9lqFIK/4)

Если нужна поддержка нулей в начале строки, добавьте `0*` в начало выражения:

```
^(?!0*(?:5|[1-9]\d*[05])$)
```

См. [пример работы этого выражения](https://regex101.com/r/9lqFIK/5)

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!` - начало негативного блока предварительного просмотра вперёд, который отменяет совпадение, если сразу после текущей позиции имеется

  - `0*` - 0 и более нулей
  - `(?:` - начало незахватывающей подмаски:

    - `5` - `5`
  - `|` - или

    - `[1-9]` - цифра, отличная от нуля
    - `\d*` - 0 и более цифр
    - `[05]` - цифра `0` или `5`
  - `)` - конец незахватывающей подмаски
  - `$` - конец строки
- `)` - конец блока предварительного просмотра вперёд.

Comment: Автору надо *для **исключения** чисел, делящихся на 5 нацело* - т.е. с точностью до наоборота. Кажется...

Comment: @Akina Да, пожалуй. Ваш комментарий сбил меня с толку. :)

Comment: o_O Мой коммент? гм... а чем?